# Pre calculus problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The perimeter of the base of a crate cannot exceed $6$ feet. The height is $1$ foot less than twice the width.

Write the volume as a function of $x$. What are the dimensions of the crate with the greatest volume?

Comment: What is $x$? Is it a square base?

Comment: I am assuming it is either a rectangle or a square

Comment: But it is never established what $x$ is.  Is it a side of the base(reasonable assumption)?

Comment: It is the width

Comment: Let Width$=x$ and breadth$=y$ then $2(x+y)=6 \Rightarrow x+y=3 \Rightarrow y=3-x$ ;

volume$=x*y*(2x-1)\Rightarrow $ volume $ = x(3-x)(2x-1)$

Answer (score 0):

If you let the width = $x$ and you know that the width plus length of the base equals 3, then you now have an expression for length.  The height is twice the width -1, so now you have an expression for that.

The volume will just be the product of these three expressions.  Do you know how to find the maxima/minima of a polynomial?

Comment: I'm not sure what my implied domain is

Comment: @user208003  You know that the width must be positive and that the length plus the width sum to $3~\text{ft}$, so $0~\text{ft} < w < 3~\text{ft}$.